# What's the difference between GAE Search API and Datastore queries?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-search-api

I'm trying to understand which one of the search API or querying the datastore will be the most accurate for a search engine in my app.

I want something very scalable and fast. That's mean be able to find something among up to millions results and very quickly. I mean as soon as a data has been registered , this one must be immediately searchable.

I'm seeking to make an autocomplete search system inspired by the google search system (with suggested results in real time).

So, what is the more appropriate option to use for A google app engine user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Search API and the Datastore are very fast, and their performance is not dependent on the number of documents that you index.

Search API was specifically designed to index text documents. This means you can search for text *inside* these text documents, and any other fields that you store in the index. Search API only supports full-word search.

The Datastore will not allow you to index text inside your documents. The Datastore, however, allows searching for entries that *start* with a specific character sequence.

Neither of these platforms will meet your requirements out of the box. Personally, I used the Datastore to build a search engine for music meta-data (artist names, album and recording titles) which supports both search inside a text string and suggestions (entries that contain words at any position which start with a specific character sequence). I had to implement my own inverted index to accomplish that. It works very well, especially in combination with Memcache.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think the datastore is the best option for me because my search engine must be based on suggestions, so i need something that let the user doing approximative search. But i think i understood the purpose of the search API and now i know in which case i might be required to use one or the other one.

Comment: Glad I could help. You may consider accepting my answer at some point :)

Comment: @AndreiVolgin what do you mean by searching inside the documents? Searching inside the files exists on GCS?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Would you mind describing a little bit more how you did to implement "your own iverted index"? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AvinashRaj:  Datastore only indexes short String properties, and you can only compare the entire String with your search keyword. Thus, if you are looking for all entities that contain the word "book" somewhere inside a long string, it's not possible.  Google Cloud Storage also has no search/indexing functionality. It's a pure file storage.

Comment: @3371862: Comments are too short for this :)  Basically, you need to store each word that you find in any document (in my case, artist names, release or recording titles) in a separate entity, and provide a list of document entities that contain this word. Depending on the size and content of your corpus you may end up with hundreds of thousands of "word entities", but the search will work very fast, you can find words that start with a given sequence of characters, and you can search for multiple words.